# How can I change the default viewer of psql results from 'more' to 'less' on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, psql

I am on a windows box, using git bash to run psql on the commandline. (not sure if that is relevant)

In psql I do a select * from table, and the results are displayed in `more`, instead of `less`. (on my ubunutu box, the results are displayed in `less`.)

How do you specify which tool to use with the results of a select statement in psql?

I have tried reading the psql commandline online documentation, (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/app-psql.html) but if the answer is there, I am missing it.
I have tried running in the windows command window, same behavior.

I am expecting to be able to set the 'veiwer' to be `less` somewhere in the psql settings, so that the results come in `less` instead of `more`.

EDIT: I think this has something to do with the PAGER environment variable, but setting `PAGER=less` in my .bashrc does not change anything.

Comment: Another update
running psql in the windows cmd shell, instead of bash seems to be the preferred method.
Still not sure how to set the PAGER in windows